# Training Regression Models to Predict Continuous Probability Values in [0, 1]

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, supervised-learning, h2o

I'm working on a machine learning project where my target variable represents continuous probability values that must fall within $[0, 1]$. While I understand regression models are suitable for this task, ensuring the predicted values remain within the desired range is quite difficult. The only thing I can think of is to transform the target into logit and then proceed it using GLM (or any other algorithms), i.e.
$$
\ln\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)=\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}
$$
but interpreting the model and its outcomes would be a challenging task. Hence, I'd like to ask:

1. Which regression algorithms are well-suited for predicting continuous probability values?
2. What preprocessing steps and feature engineering techniques should I consider when working with such target variables?

In addition, I'm particularly interested in using H2O and/or other Python packages for this task, therefore I'd like to know:

1. How can I leverage the H2O Python library for training regression models that predict continuous probability values? Are there any specific features or functions in H2O that are beneficial for this task?
2. Are there other Python packages or libraries that are well-suited for this type of regression problem?

I'm eager to hear about practical experiences and any potential pitfalls to avoid when working on projects involving continuous probability values. Any insights or resources you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "*...interpreting the model and its outcomes would be a challenging task*" Why is this challenging? Logistic regression is well-established and even if odds ratios can be tricky, all you need to do is use predicted probabilities.

Comment: If your logistic model gives a coefficient $\beta_i$, you are saying that an increase in $x_i$ of $1$ adds $\beta_i$ to the log-odds, so multiplies the odds by $e^{\beta_i}$.  The effect on the probability depends on where you start: if you start with a probability close to $0$ then this multiplies it by almost $e^{\beta_i}$, while if you   start with a probability close to $1$ then this divides the complementary probability (the probability of the event not happening) by almost $e^{\beta_i}$.  This is reasonably simple to explain and your predicted probabilities never get outside $(0,1)$

Comment: Since DR Cox developed binary logistic regression in 1958 for exactly this problem I'm not seeing the challenge in using it.